# Different behavior on read() depending on file descriptor representing a file, anonymous pipe or socket when writing to non writable memory

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

I have the following code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
        char *p = (char *)mmap(0, 0x3000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        munmap(p + 0x2000, 0x1000);
        p += 0x800;
        printf("%zd\n", read(0, p, 0x3000));
        return 0;
}
```

When compiling it and running it with input that will write past writable memory, I get different behaviors based on the way this input is fed:

```
$ python3 -c 'print("A"*0x3000)' | ./test
4096
$ python3 -c 'print("A"*0x3000)' > input.bin; ./test < input.bin
6144
$ nc.traditional -l -p 1337 -e ./test &
[1] 25855
$ python3 -c 'print("A"*0x3000)' | nc localhost 1337
-1
[1]+  Done                    nc.traditional -l -p 1337 -e ./test
```

I would have expected the read() call to return the same result in all cases, but this is not the case. Why do I get different behaviors?

Comment: Why do you expect -1 in all cases? There are 6144 bytes which can be read. Nonetheless, I would never rely on OS behavior, when I give unmapped memory to it.

Comment: `read` can return less than the requested number of bytes, and that is not an error. It shouldn't return more than 6144 bytes in this case due to the unmapped memory beyond that.

Comment: Surely the one-page result from the pipe is not a coincidence, but it’s odd that it’s exactly the middle half of the mapped region.

Comment: @DavisHerring On Linux, `PIPE_BUF` is 4096. Writes longer than `PIPE_BUF` to a pipe may be non-atomic.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Good point—I thought it was larger.

Comment: @DavisHerring The pipe capacity is larger - usually 65536 (16 pages), but changeable on Linux, but `PIPE_BUF` is still 4096. Another possibility is that the python command might calling `write` with a maximum length of 4096, but I don't know.

Comment: @IanAbbott strace showed that Python is writing its output in two writes: first the 0x3000 A's, then a newline. So I do not think this is the explanation.

Comment: @B3n I have considered your point about strace, done a bit of detective work in the kernel source code, and posted an answer with what I think is the reason why only 4096 bytes were read from the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strace output from this command shows that the full 12288 (0x3000) bytes are written in one go:

```
$ strace python3 -c 'print("A"*0x3000)' | ./test
...
write(1, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"..., 12288) = 12288
...
```

Using strace on the `./test` command at the other end of the pipe shows that only 4096 (0x1000) bytes are read:

```
$ python3 -c 'print("A"*0x3000)' | strace ./test
...
read(0, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"..., 12288) = 4096
...
```

If the standard input for `./test` comes from `input.bin` (which contains 12288 'A's followed by a newline), strace shows that 6144 (0x1800) bytes are read:

```
$ strace ./test < input.bin
...
read(0, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"..., 12288) = 6144
...
```

I think the explanation can only be found by delving into the kernel's code for reading from a pipe in the `pipe_read` function in "fs/pipe.c". Internally, the pipe contains a cyclic array of `struct pipe_buffer`, each of which contains a pointer to a page of data. The `pipe_read` function loops through these buffers copying the contents to the user until all requested data has been read, there is nothing left in the pipe (after waiting for more data from the writer when in blocking mode), or a fault occurs when copying data to the user. The reason why only 4096 bytes are returned instead of 6144 when the fault occurs seems to be due to this bit of code:

```
        written = copy_page_to_iter(buf->page, buf->offset, chars, to);
        if (unlikely(written < chars)) {
            if (!ret)
                ret = -EFAULT;
            break;
        }
        ret += chars;
        buf->offset += chars;
        buf->len -= chars;
```

(The above section is from Linux kernel version 4.19.)

Here, `chars` is the amount to be copied from the current pipe buffer, `written` is the amount that was actually copied, and `ret` is the return value of the function, which is normally the number of bytes read. The initial value of `ret` is 0. `written` normally gets set to `chars` unless an address fault occurs, in which case it will be less than `chars`.

The fault occurs when copying the second page from the pipe. The first page was copied successfully so `ret` will be 4096. When copying the second page, an address fault occurs in the user buffer after 6144 - 4096 = 2048 (0x800) bytes, so the `break;` statement is reached to break out of the loop before the `ret += chars;` statement is reached. `ret` is not set to `-EFAULT` because it is non-zero. However, the partial copy of 2048 bytes from the second page of the pipe to the user buffer have been disregarded as far as the returned value of the `pipe_buf` function indicates. (The disregarded data is not discarded from the pipe. The position in the pipe is only moved on after a successful copy, so a subsequent call to `pipe_read` will continue from the same point.)

Note that although `read` only returned 4096, it seems likely that it actually copied 6144 bytes to the user buffer. This could be confirmed by examining the buffer contents from `p + 4096` onwards after returning from the `read` call.

I'm sure the relevant part of the `pipe_read` function could be rewritten to properly account for the partially copied portion, but I don't know if the core kernel developers would consider it a bug worth fixing.  For example, a fix might replace the above code with something like the following (untested) code:

```
        written = copy_page_to_iter(buf->page, buf->offset, chars, to);
        ret += written;
        buf->offset += written;
        buf->len -= written;
        if (unlikely(written < chars)) {
            if (!ret)
                ret = -EFAULT;
            break;
        }
```

I am pretty sure that your `./test` program would manage to read 6144 bytes from the pipe with this change to the kernel code.

Comment: You are totally right, there are actually 6144 bytes copied, although it returns only 4096. I guess this might be dangerous in some cases where programmers assume only 4096 bytes have been written to their buffer. Also, if you compare it with the code of `do_generic_file_read` (for the case where the file descriptor represents a file, there the return value gets updated before it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: @B3n POSIX doesn't have anything to say about the contents of the user buffer beyond the returned amount, or when an error is returned, so it would be unsafe for programmers to assume anything about those contents.

Comment: This answer explains very well the case where the file descriptor represents a pipe. I have written a similar (somewhat longer) thing up on this question here: https://medium.com/@benoit.sevens/reading-from-a-file-pipe-or-socket-is-not-the-same-4675e364c536 which also handles the file and socket case.

Comment: @B3n Nice write-up!